# How to use Html.Action's RouteValueDictionary values in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Here i am using `Html.Action` to display a set of books in (Books.cshtml) partial page.

I am passing *Route Dictionary* values in action but I don't have any idea about how to get *Route Dictionary* values in `Controller` and also is it possible to get `Route Dictionary` values in Partial page("Books.cshtml").

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{RouteValueDictionary objRoute = new RouteValueDictionary();
  objRoute.Add("Book1", "DavinciCode");
  objRoute.Add("Book2", "Pirates");
  objRoute.Add("Book3", "Ghost");
}

@Html.Action("Books", "Home", objRoute)
```

**Books.cshtml(Partial Page)**

```
<p style="color:Blue;">
    The list of books are as folows
        <p>@ Book items</p>  
    //Here I need to display list of books (i.e) routevalue Dictionary values
</p>
```

**HomeController:**

```
public ActionResult Books()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access route data along the lines of:

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using a `RouteValueDictionary` to store your model in is the best idea. You can use a model with your partial view too, you know.

I would make a model for the partial view, which represents the data you need, i.e. a list of `Book`s. On the `Book`, you put the necessary data for each book, including the key needed to display the detail view of the book (i.e. an `Id` property):

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; internal set; }
    public string Name { get; internal set; }
    // ...
}
```

Then you make your partial view have a model of e.g. `List<Book>`, in `Books.cshtml`:

```
@model IList<Book>


<p style="color:Blue;">
     The list of books are as follows:

     <ul>
          @foreach (var book in @Model)
          {
               @Html.ActionLink(book.Name, "BookDetails", new { id = book.Id }) 
          }
     </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution, Its working fine for me.

CONTROLLER :

```
public ActionResult Books()
{
   Dictionary<int, string> books = new Dictionary<int, string>() { 
              { 1, "ASP.NET MVC #" }, 
              { 2, "C#" }, 
              { 3, "Razor View" } };
   return PartialView("Books", books);
}
```

PARTIAL VIEW :

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@model Dictionary<int, string>
<h2>The list of books are as follows:</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var book in @Model)
    {
        <li><a href="/Home/BookDetails/@book.Key">@book.Value</a></li> 
    }
</ul>
```

IN VIEW ( Wherever you want to display the list of books)

```
@Html.Action("Books", "YOURCONTROLLERNAME")
```

Answer (score -1):

They should appear as method arguments - you just have to declare the ones you're interested in:

```
public ActionResult Books(string Book1, string Book2, string Book3)
{
    return PartialView();
}
```